# How can I correct this code in java

Tags: java

I have a `String` and the following code. I'm trying to determine if the `String` is empty, and if so to print `-1`; however, my condition `if (tmp == null)` does not appear to correctly tell me if the `String` is empty or not. How can I determine if a `String` is empty?

```
public static void main(String[] args)  
{  
    combine(1);   
    for(String tmp : set)
        if (tmp == null)
        {
            System.out.print(-1);
        }

        else
        {  
            System.out.println(tmp); 
        } 

}
```

Comment: Which `String`? What is `set`? What is `combine`? What are you asking? The system is giving you much more than just -1.

Comment: i pass the string set to tmp so if set is empty then tmp is empty.

Comment: I misunderstood, you want your application to display one or you want the process to exit with an exit code of -1? Again, what are `set` and `combine`? Edit your question, show us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if it's empty you need to do just that,

```
if (tmp.isEmpty())
```

or if there might be whitespace within it:

```
if (tmp.trim().isEmpty())
```

or if it might also be null, then:

```
if (tmp == null || tmp.trim().isEmpty())
```